# Concept of combinations and number theory.

Tags: number-theory, combinations

The number of six digit numbers of the form ababab(in base ten)each of which is a product of exactly six distinct primes?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! When posting a question, specify what you are asking and include any previous attempts on the question.

Comment: @ZainPatel Kindly excuse me this time sir. I will follow the procedure from next posts.

Comment: You can edit this post by pressing the grey edit button at the bottom. :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $(ababab) = 10101\cdot ab = 3\cdot 7\cdot 13\cdot 37\cdot (ab)$.

You need to compute the amount of two digit numbers that are a product of two distinct prime numbers other than $3,7,13,37$.